How do I stop Vector crashing when an empty line is logged?
I'm new to Vector and was trying to monitor some of my existing containers, but one of them outputs an empty line of text and this causes Vector to crash with:

thread 'vector-worker' panicked at src/sinks/aws_cloudwatch_logs/request_builder.rs:111:52:
payload should never be zero length

I have a very simple config:
sources:
    dummy_logs:
        type: "docker_logs"
        docker_host: "/path_to/docker.sock"

sinks:
    print:
        type: "aws_cloudwatch_logs"
        inputs: ["dummy_logs"]
        group_name: "/my/group"
        stream_name: "%Y/%m/%d/my-stream"
        encoding:
            codec: "text"


It's easy to reproduce. Run these command in separate windows:
vector --config my_config.yaml

docker run -it --rm alpine /bin/sh

Then, inside the docker shell:

ls  - this works file


echo - this, on its own, causes Vector to exit


Try adding a filter transform
transforms:
  my_transform_id:
    type: filter
    inputs: ["dummy_logs"]
    condition: .message != ""


Thanks, yes that fixed it.
I'm just surprised Vector is so fragile that it panics and exits simply because something that its monitoring outputs an empty line.

Glad it worked for you. I think this is a specific limitation of the AWS Cloudwatch sink rather than Vector itself, though I'm not sure of the downstream reason
